# How to make my answers appear as decimals?

Tags: c++

I have read the first 50 or so pages in my C++ book and armed with
that knowledge I have attempted to create a program that 
calculates two measurements of a circle from one, this is what
I have come up with:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main(int nNumberofArgs, char* pszArgs[])
{
    string op;
    int r;
    int a;
    int d;
    int val;

    cout << "This program aims to calculate two measurements of a cicle from one measurement" << endl;
    cout << "Enter the measurement you wish to input from a choice of r, d or a" << endl;
    cin >> op;

    cout << "Please enter the value of this measurement" << endl;
    cin >> val;

    if (op == "r") {
        a = val * val * 3.14;
        d = val * 2;
        r = val;
    }

    if (op == "d") {
        a = val / 2 * val / 2 * 3.14;
        d = val;
        r = val / 2;
    }

    if (op == "a"){
        a = val;
        d = (sqrt(val / 3.14)) * 2;
        r = (sqrt(val / 3.14));
    }

    cout << "The area is " << endl;
    cout << std::setprecision(3) << a << endl;

    cout << "The diameter is  " << endl;
    cout << std::setprecision(3) << d << endl;

    cout << "The radius is " << endl;
    cout << std::setprecision(3) << r << endl;
}
```

The problem I have is that my answers all come out with no decimals, as you can see I have tried to incorporate "setprecision" but it hasn't worked.

Comment: Please try to post the [minimal code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that is required to reproduce the error!

Comment: You are using `int`s. Why do you expect to get decimals?

Comment: Also, turn up your warnings and read them

Comment: Like i said I have literally about 2 days worth of casual reading and messing about that can be counted as experience. I had no idea that using int was anyway bad. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 5):

Replace `int` with `double`:

```
int r;
int a;
int d;
int val;
```

Answer (score 3):

`std::set_precision` only does what you expect when applied to floating-point types, like `float` or `double`. I suspect that most of your problems would be solved if you used one of these types rather than `int`s